# Error pulling Google Drive File list

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to pull a page of user documents on a specific user.  I have tried to reach out to Google support to troubleshoot the issue but they did not help in the issue.  When I pull this particular user's file list I receive the error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: number field formatted as a JSON string must use the @JsonString annotation [key aperture, field private java.lang.Float com.google.api.services.drive.model.File$ImageMediaMetadata.aperture]
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:69)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:789)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:438)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:745)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:438)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:745)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseArray(JsonParser.java:610)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:708)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:438)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:745)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:358)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:331)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

To me this looks like a Java Client Library parsing issue but I would like to bring it to the attention of someone in the Drive team to have them look at it.

The code to produce this error is as following :

```
Files.List request = service.files().list();
FileList files = request.execute();
```

Comment: Your code to reproduce this error please...

Comment: Are you using the "@JSonString annotation"? Maybe a little bit more code would help.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with the generated model classes and it's choking on the aperture field in the image metadata. Can you post a sample of the raw JSON for that file? Also would help if you could make sure you're on the latest client. They type for that field shouldn't have changed or anything, but good to rule that out just in case...

Comment: I have the exact same issue as ndixon using the latest library in the maven repo : com.google.apis.google-api-services-drive-v2-rev105-1.17.0-rc



  Here is a file with the issue : the "aperture" field is not a number but a string having the "Infinity" value.

{
  ...
  "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
  ...
  "createdDate": "2013-11-27T03:09:08.457Z",
  ...
  "originalFilename": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.jpg",
  "fileExtension": "jpg",
  "imageMediaMetadata": {
  ...
  "aperture": "Infinity",
  }
}